# Timestamp generated datatype by code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I should have timestamp datatype row inside my SQL Server database. I'm using code-first approach so I want to generate this field from my domain util class.

So, how to declare this property to be generated as timestamp in the database?

Comment: Do you want the database to store a timestamp on insert or update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a byte array decorated with the [`[Timestamp]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.timestampattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[Timestamp] 
public byte[] SomeTimestamp { get; set; }
```

You might also want to checkout the [`following article`](http://www.undisciplinedbytes.com/2012/03/creating-a-timestamp-column-with-entity-framework/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this sample

```
...
       public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }

     public class UserModelConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<User> {
            public UserModelConfiguration() {
                Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsRowVersion();            
            }
        }
```